# How to let Kafka in the NestJs read the env file?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, nestjs

I am working on a nestjs project using Kafka microservices (import from @nestjs/microservices).

for listening to a message, I am using the following code in main.ts:

```
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        transport: Transport.KAFKA,
        options: {
          client: {
            brokers: configService.get('brokers'),
          },
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    },
  );

      await app.listen();
```

I am trying to let the nestjs read brokers from .env.

It can not work.

and I got error :

```
Argument of type '{ imports: (typeof ConfigModule)[]; useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => Promise<{ transport: Transport; options: { client: { brokers: any; }; }; }>; inject: (typeof ConfigService)[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NestApplicationContextOptions & MicroserviceOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'imports' does not exist in type 'NestApplicationContextOptions & MicroserviceOptions'.
```

if delete 'imports: [ConfigModule]', I have the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => Promise<{ transport: Transport; options: { client: { brokers: any; }; }; }>; inject: (typeof ConfigService)[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NestApplicationContextOptions & MicroserviceOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'useFactory' does not exist in type 'NestApplicationContextOptions & MicroserviceOptions'.
```

Please help :)

Comment: using `ClientsModule.registerAsync` is the way to inject your `ConfigService` to retrieve env. vars. Edit your question to show us how you're using it

Comment: Hi , I have update the code.

Comment: `createMicroservice` doesn't have that second parameter. It's just allows `{ transport, options }`. See https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

as I see that you included config module at root level, and you did not initialize it. I think you should add Config Module like below.

```
imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    someModule,
    fooModule,
  ],
     useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
       transport: Transport.KAFKA,
       options: {
         client: {
           brokers: configService.get('brokers'),
         },
       },
     }),
     inject: [ConfigService],
})
```